# A word for misplaced recognition

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a scene where my male protagonist turns to see someone he doesn't know, but who reminds him instantly of his wife.

The wife's golden curls are used throughout as a theme and symbol, so the reader should know what I'm hinting at.

I tried to work with "...golden curls reminiscent of [wife's name]", but it's too wordy. Also, it feels redundant, but "...reminiscent golden curls" is gibberish.

I'm looking for something that will fit this sample sentence, but will happily restructure it if I find a good word:

"He was taken aback by the [WORD GOES HERE] of her golden curls."

So I tried *familiarity*, which makes it seem like he recognizes (and is possibly even close with) this new character.

What I'm looking for is a single word for that moment when you recognize something from one person in another. A kind of transferred familiarity, or misplaced recognition. No, I don't think any of those will work either.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried looking up "reminiscent" in a thesaurus? And can you provide an exact sentence [like it says here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)?

Comment: @StuartF The thesaurus says it means "similar to" which is how I understood it to begin with, and which is why it needs the person to be compared to. Also, the link you gave asked for a SAMPLE sentence, not the EXACT one, which would contain extraneous info. I'll edit the question to expand the phrase into a sentence, but it won't add much.

Comment: This is strictly opinion. I like *familiarity*. The curls seem familiar because of memory, not that this woman's curls are familiar. So they seem that way because of the past. The word *familiar* forces the reader to connect the dots - I think that's ideal for the writer.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's the best I could come up with. Post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Even if you stick with 'familiarity', I'd consider restructuring the sentence. I know it is a sample, not the specific sentence, but introducing his emotional response before the thing that causes it it weakens the impact. If you are sold on having the reaction first, delaying the revelation of cause a bit further gives a little tension. 'John felt a wave of emotion he couldn't account for when he was first introduced to Jane. It took his heart a couple of beats to settle and realize it was the curling familiarity of her golden hair that had thrown him for a loop.'

Comment: @Spagirl That's a brilliant point. Thank you so much for highlighting it 